# How can I access my router that is on other office network

Tags: routing, router, route

Hi I'm working on ROUTER A and I want to access ROUTER C, the config is:

ROUTER A <-conected with-> ROUTER B <-conected with-> ROUTER C

ROUTER A: LAN:192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 WAN:79.189.60.243 255.255.255.0

ROUTER B: LAN:79.189.60.241 255.255.255.0 WAN: INTERNET ACCESS

ROUTER C: LAN:192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 WAN:79.189.60.242 255.255.255.0

Router A and C gets 79...IP from a Router B by DHCP.

I tried to configure static route on Router A and Router B that can lead packets from A through B to C but seams not working. Still I get no response from network 192.168.0.1. Can anybody help ?

EDIT:
OK thanks to user: Gnouc, I configured the network as shown below:
[LINK TO IMG](http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/134/d/4/net_by_nightkn8-d65brqa.png)

It looks quite ok but still I can not acces Routers A from C and C from A.

P.S. 
With rep under 10 I can not insert images here sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

As you said, I think you have missed config in router C. You must config a static route on router C to network 192.168.1.0. Some thing like:

```
route outside 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 <gateway - IP from router B>
```

Where `IP from router B` is in the same network with router C.

**Edited**

Here I will discibe your topology:

> ```
>                                 (www)
>                                   |
> ```
>
> (192.168.1.0)RouterA(79.189.60.243)--- RouterB
>   ---(79.189.60.242)RouterC(192.168.0.0)
>
> ```
>                             (79.189.60.241)
> ```

As your topo, It's very strange that external interface in router A and C in the same subnet. But If from router A, you can ping router C and vice versa. You should config like this:

```
In router A: route outside 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 79.189.60.242
In router C: route outside 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 79.189.60.243
```

Then from 192.168.1.0 subnet, you can communicate wit 192.168.0.0 subnet.

Comment: OK. I configured the network as shown below: [LINK](http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/134/d/4/net_by_nightkn8-d65brqa.png)
It looks quite ok but still I can not acces Routers A from C and C from A.

Comment: As your link, your config is failed. Why the gateway to 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 is the same? Please give me your topology.

Comment: [link](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/134/5/f/nic_by_nightkn8-d65btag.png) here you go.

Comment: Stil I get nothing, not even ping from A or C, however ping works fine on 79.189.60.242 and 79.189.60.243 but still no response from 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1

Comment: Do you own the 79.189.60.0 network? Please provide your ouput of traceroute command from A to C.

Comment: 79.189.60.0 is from my ISP but I can configure 79.189.60.1 router, from tracert A to C I get * * * Time out

Comment: For traffic from Lan to External, you are using `NAT` or `ROUTE`. Also check accesslist in routers.

Maybe you don't own 79.189.60.0, so that you can't route private IP.

Comment: I got DIR-655 and DIR-100 Routers, I don't see any option that could change that. I found a good tutorial [link](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Subnets_with_Static_Routes) , but I have no idea where can I ACCEPT incoming packets from other routers. Here is a simulator of one of the routers I have [link](http://support.dlink.com/emulators/dir655/133NA/Device_Info.html)